# Python selenium xpath using contains and not contains

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try to get links whose title contains some word in the mean time not contains some words, I use the following code but it says is not a valid XPath expression.

Please find my code here:

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
driver.get("http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml")
while True:
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[(contains(@title,'公司债券')and not(contains(@title,'短期'))]")]
    for link in links:
               driver.get(link)
               #dosth
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an extra bracket in you xpath, use

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'公司债券')and not(contains(@title,'短期'))]")]
```

instead
You can use chrome developer tools first to validate your xpaths
[image]
PS: I changed the xpath here a bit to be able to find some elements in my page

Comment: Thank you Merolla, it worked! but may I know how could I find the chrome developer? I click inspect, but no such tool, thanks!

Comment: Inspect is another way to open the developer tools, in fact you can open it in 3 ways: right click=> inspect, click the 3 dots in chrome toolbar=> More tools=>Developer tools or hit CTRL+SHIFT+I. Once you open it hit CTRL+F and you can search for elements by id, xpath or CSS selector.

Comment: Got it , thank you so much! may I ask if I want to choose multiple 'not contains' conditions like: find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'公司债券')and not(contains(@title,'短期')and not(contains(@title,'非公开'))]")], is that correct?

Comment: There is a missing bracket in your xpath, use //a[contains(@title,'公司债券')and not(contains(@title,'短期'))and not(contains(@title,'非公开'))] instead.

Answer (score 1):

There should be space before `and`. Also there is extra leading bracket in your XPath. Try:

```
"//a[contains(@title,'公司债券') and not(contains(@title,'短期'))]"
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your help! may I also ask  if I want to choose multiple 'not contains' conditions like: find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'公司债券')and not(contains(@title,'短期')and not(contains(@title,'非公开'))]")], is that correct?

Comment: @Cathy Yes, that's correct. But don't forget to add space to `)and`

Comment: Hi Jason, but somehow it says is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Cathy you need to replace this part `and not(contains(@title,'短期') and` with `and not(contains(@title,'短期')) and` (note missed clothing bracket)

Comment: @JaSON Why does she need to add a space between the bracket and "and"? I tried the following with Selenium Java
 `if ( driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Container')and not(contains(@class,'top'))]")).size() > 0 ) `
                `System.out.println("Element is found");`
and the output was "Element is found." 
I don't think it would differ with Python.

Comment: @Merolla yes, you're right. It seem that we might not need spaces in case bracket before or after operator. But note that in common no space before or after operator will lead to `SyntaxError`. Also it improves readability